# Extendable reusable app

Tags: django

I have the need for a reusable and extendable app for django, but am unsure on how to design it.

The reusable app is a double entry accounting system. The app has a few models, most importantly an Account and a Transaction model. Transactions depend (indirectly) on Account. Implementing this part by itself is not a problem and I have a good sense of how the system would work if it were on its own.

Problems arise when I try to implement this as a reusable app. I have two main issues that needs to be solved. Firstly, I would like there to be a separation between each app that uses the accounting app, i.e. app A should not be able to access accounting data created by app B and vice versa. Secondly, the apps using the account app usually needs to associate an account to some other entity, e.g. a client, guest, contractor etc. In order to be able to find accounts belonging to a each entity.

The more I think about it the more I am leaning towards just defining an interface (Mixins?) and use duck typing to have the accounting app contain common functionality (mostly reports) and let each app define the Account and Transaction models it needs. I get great separation, but some lack of reusability which I can live with. It would be neat to have a central accounting app that does the two things above, but it feels impossible to get both the extensibility and reuseability at the same time.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've only just joined SO, but obviously already have a great understanding of programming. From what Ninja academy do you hail from?

Comment: Thanks. Mostly been stalking SO in the past, felt it was time to join in on the fun. Learned my skills the old way; hammering on a keyboard for 20 years.